# Why do I need to use two services in my app?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing a MMS-like app on the advanced interphone for the airport using private network. I receive the messages from the specific server using socket. If the user log on the message system, the user should always receive the messages until he logout.

My idea to solve such issue is as follows:

1. By using one local service as a Manager service, this service will receive the command from the UI,and one remote service to maintain the connection with the server.
2. When the local service receive the different cmd from UI, it will check the ***UserState*** stored in a Application sub-class, then send the required information to the remote service.
3. The remote service will generate different message-packets to send to the server.
4. While the receiving procedure is like: After the remote service receiving and parsing different messages(such as sms,address list of contacts), it send necessary strings, file URI or object to the local service, and the local service send the info to the activity.

I don't know whether this idea will work well. For I need a Role like Manager to handle different sending cmd and receving messages and a consistent connection, what the structure should my app be like?

Comment: I didn't read that in too much details, but I would use one service with Threads and maybe a ThreadPoolManager, one service is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you tell me an method how to make the connection service is always running?For in service document, local service can be killed more easily than a remote service(running in its own process) by the system.

Answer (score 0):

> use one local service as a Manager service,this service will receive the command from the UI,and one remote service to maintain the connection with the server.

No. Use one local service, period. A second service adds no value; a remote service makes your app worse, not better, by wasting RAM, CPU, and battery for no benefit.

> can you tell me an method how to make the connection service is always running?

You cannot have a service running "always". If you use `startService()` and `startForeground()`, it will be the least likely to be automatically terminated. However, the user can elect to force-stop your app or use a task killer if they so choose.

> For in service document, local service can be killed more easily than a remote service(running in its own process) by the system.

That is incorrect.

Comment: can you tell me whether or not could I integarte this app to the SYSTEM like MMS or receveing telphone.For in our devices, this app should not be able deleted or closed.Can you give me some advice how to do that?